# How to save associated defect ID while upload Test Results to Polarion

Tags: xml, junit, polarion

I work with Polarion and would like to save information about a failed test and associated defect. I use the following XML file to upload the test result for a Test Run:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<testsuite>
    <testcase time="377.984" classname="com.dbu.ecm.ethes.ftests.login.ForgotYourPassword" name="testFailedDefect"><failure message="fail_message" type="fail_type">Comment</failure></testcase>

</testsuite>
```

For example, I would like to save "AR-13333" defect identifier
Is it possible by adding something to the XML file?

Thank you in advance. Antony.